# Multiple Numbers on a same line, but need to count the line as 1

Tags: grep

My sample file has several lines like this

```
27809, shbd.dav, 165 .
27673 ; matroshka;  223665;
```

I need to count the lines containing digits.
So the output should be 2.

I only have to use grep to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
grep -c '[[:digit:]]' infile
```

replace `[[:digit:]]` with `[0123456789]` if you want restrict digits to only English digits (see [Difference between `[0-9]`, `[[:digit:]]` and `\d`](/q/414226/72456)).

Comment: Personally, I prefer `[[:digit:]]`, and then the user can just set `LC_ALL=C` if they need ASCII digits.